# bash extglob: Should the order of patterns in a pattern list matter?

Tags: bash, wildcards

According to the bash manual, if `extglob` is enabled,
the pattern `@(pattern-list)` should match any of the patterns in `pattern-list` (separated by `|`). Here it works as expected:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ ls -ld /@(.|usr)/@(.|local)/@(.|share)/
drwxr-xr-x  50 root root   4096 Sep  2 16:39 /./././
drwxr-xr-x  12 root root   4096 Oct 15  2018 /usr/././
drwxrwsr-x  10 root staff  4096 Oct 15  2018 /usr/local/./
drwxrwsr-x  10 root staff  4096 Oct 15  2018 /usr/local/share/
drwxr-xr-x 725 root root  20480 Sep  2 16:42 /usr/./share/
```

But if we swap the alternatives in each of the three pattern lists,
most of the directories that should have been matched are gone:

```
$ ls -ld /@(usr|.)/@(local|.)/@(share|.)/
drwxrwsr-x 10 root staff 4096 Oct 15  2018 /usr/local/share/
```

The same with a non-existing subdirectory. Here it works:

```
$ ls -ld /@(.|usr)/@(.|foo)/@(.|share)/
drwxr-xr-x  50 root root  4096 Sep  2 16:39 /./././
drwxr-xr-x  12 root root  4096 Oct 15  2018 /usr/././
drwxr-xr-x 725 root root 20480 Sep  2 16:42 /usr/./share/
```

And here it doesn't:

```
$ ls -ld /@(usr|.)/@(foo|.)/@(share|.)/
ls: cannot access '/@(usr|.)/@(foo|.)/@(share|.)/': No such file or directory
```

What's going on here? Is this behavior documented somewhere, or is it just plain buggy? (This is GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1).)

Comment: The last error will go away if you `shopt -s nullglob`, or use `shopt -s failglob` for a "better" error.

Comment: This is a really interesting question. The first pattern acting halfway between the 2nd and the brace expanding `/{.,usr}/{.,local}/{.,share}/` is really weird.

Comment: Further data points: bash version 5 acts this same way. For bash version 3.2, the 1st pattern acts the same as the 2nd. Something changed in version 4.x -- if you're feeling intrepid, wade through https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES

Comment: @glennjackman The exact output depends of course on which directories are
present in the filesystem. For me, the only difference between the first
pattern and your brace pattern is that the latter expands also to non-existing
directories such as /././share/, resulting in an error message by ls. But that
difference is to be expected; it's the same difference as between
"echo /[uv]sr" and "echo /{u,v}sr".

Comment: Yes agreed. That's because [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) is **not** [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) -- brace expansion just generates strings.

Answer (score 2):

Prior to bash-4.3, the "." term would never match. From bash(1), v5.0, section *Pathname Expansion*:

> ```
>                                                 When a  pattern  is  used
>   for  pathname expansion, the character ``.''  at the start of a name or
>   immediately following a slash must be matched  explicitly,  unless  the
>   shell  option  dotglob  is  set.  The filenames ``.''  and ``..''  must
>   always be matched explicitly, even if dotglob is set.
> ```

The description of the behaviour here is a little vague, but it *doesn't* mean that "." must be at the start of each (sub-)pattern, you can prove that with:

```
$ echo  /@(usr|.)/@(local|.)/@(share|.)/
/usr/local/share/
$ echo  /@(usr|..)/@(local|..)/@(share|..)/
/../../../ /usr/../../ /usr/local/../ /usr/local/share/
```

So the problem is specific to "." and not "..".

I believe this is a bug in [`extglob_skipname()`](https://fossies.org/dox/bash-5.0/glob_8c_source.html#l00180), starting at line 218 in the `while (t = glob_patscan (pp, pe, '|')) { ... }` loop, the final term in such a pattern is not handled properly (interaction with the leading "." supression logic in `skipname()`) so "." never matches but ".." manages to match. (`glob_patscan` is aka `PATSCAN` thanks to macro games.)

Either of these work too:

```
$ echo  /@(usr|.|)/@(local|.|)/@(share|.|)/
/./././ /usr/././ /usr/./share/ /usr/local/./ /usr/local/share/
$ echo  /@(usr|.|.)/@(local|.|.)/@(share|.|.)/
/./././ /usr/././ /usr/./share/ /usr/local/./ /usr/local/share/
```

So the answer is the sub-pattern order shouldn't matter, and doesn't matter, but seemingly a bug causes problems when the final term is a ".".