# Pattern list in bash extglob containing a / and a |

Tags: bash, wildcards, pattern-matching, shopt

Here is a transcript of commands (and their output) that explains my problem:

```
/tmp/example $ shopt -s
cdspell         on
checkwinsize    on
cmdhist         on
complete_fullquote      on
direxpand       on
dirspell        on
expand_aliases  on
extglob         on
extquote        on
failglob        on
force_fignore   on
globstar        on
histappend      on
interactive_comments    on
login_shell     on
nocaseglob      on
nullglob        on
progcomp        on
promptvars      on
sourcepath      on

/tmp/example $ ls -R
.:
prefix_bar  prefix_foo

./prefix_bar:
test.c

./prefix_foo:
baz  test.c

./prefix_foo/baz:
test.c

/tmp/example $ ls prefix_@(foo/baz|bar)/test.c
prefix_bar/test.c

/tmp/example $ ls @(prefix_foo/baz|prefix_bar)/test.c
prefix_bar/test.c
```

Question: Why does bash ignore the `foo/baz` or the `pattern_foo/baz` portion of the pattern-list?

For the record, I looked around before posting this question and the question closest to what I am about to ask is [bash extglob: Should the order of patterns in a pattern list matter?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/548745/bash-extglob-should-the-order-of-patterns-in-a-pattern-list-matter) (and it does not answer my question).

Comment: This reply to a different question might help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/678859/58056

Comment: Yes, it does,  thank you @pfnuesel!  I used to follow Stéphane Chazelas in comp.unix.shell a lot; he is awesome!